# Print double with variable precision (not rounded) in Java

Tags: java, precision

I am looking to print a double to a variable precision, but without rounding. For example:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double num;
    System.out.println("Enter a double:");
    num = input.nextDouble();
    int precision;
    System.out.println("Enter precision:");
    precision = input.nextInt();
```

Now I want to print num to the decimal place of precision. Is there a simple way to print this?

EDIT:
I have not seen another question answered as to how to use a variable value. The DecimalFormat option rounds the number, which I do not want. Ideally, I am looking for a way to use a variable in:

```
    "%.nf"
```

rather than

```
    "%.3f"
```

Comment: The question this is considered a duplicate of does not really answer my question. I attempted to use DecimalFormat and it rounded the number.

Answer (score 1):

Use, as a formatted String, `"%.nf"`, where `n` is replaced by the number of decimal places.

Example:

```
System.out.printf("%.1f, %.2f\n", 1.234d, 1.234d);
// 1.2, 1.23
```

See [the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

To insert a variable into this, just do `"%." + intValue + "f"`.

Comment: Thanks. However, I do not know the number of decimal places beforehand so it would be impossible to use an integer value in place of n.

Comment: @user4332594 just do `"%." + intValue + "f"`.